# How to let two DIV's automatically connect to each other if in a certain area?

Tags: javascript, html

Just looking for ideas really. What i want is when two div's with images are close to eachother, to move their positions to connect to each other. Any idea's how to do this?

**HTML**

```
<body onkeyup="clearPress()" onkeydown="controlCheck(event)" style="cursor: auto;">
    <div id="application" style="position:absolute">
        <div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:300px;height:900px" role="tablist"> … </div>
        <div id="buttons" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:50px;border:2px solid grey;background: url('images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png') repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(230, 230, 230);"> … </div>
        <div id="canvas" class="DROPPABLE ui-droppable" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:850px;border:2px solid grey">
        <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 123.817px; left: 507.7px;" onclick="addBorder(this)">
            <img id="PMF00" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; width: 42px; height: 42px; top: 988.7px; left: -344.3px;" onclick="addBorder(this)"> … </div>
        <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; width: 84px; height: 36px; top: 138.7px; left: 412.467px;" onclick="addBorder(this)"> … </div>
        <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; width: 80px; height: 41px; top: 143.7px; left: 151.7px;" onclick="addBorder(this)"> … </div>
        <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 92px; left: 344px;" onclick="addBorder(this)"> … </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Look image for explanation]

Comment: You mean, snap them into place after dragging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the draggable with the snap option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ snap: true });
```

Get or set the snap option, after initialization:

```
// getter
var snap = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "snap" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "snap", true );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snap
Snap was the word i was looking for, i set snap to true and it works, thanks !